# Calling Functions Based on Content of a Dictionary C#

Tags: c#

I'm working on a program that will have a dictionary storing commands. There are two dictionaries, one of executables and one of internal functions. Right now, I'm just using the executable one, which has a command name attached to the path of the executable. It will check for the input in the dictionary and run the attached exe if possible and run that command. I started the function dictionary because there are some functions that are not executables. Would it be possible to do the same thing I did with the executables with functions inside the program?

```
    private Dictionary<string, string> ExternalCommands = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"help", @".\help.exe"}
    };


    private Dictionary<string, string> InternalFunctions = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        **{"exit", function()}**
    };
    public int Execute(string input)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ExternalCommands.Keys.Contains(input))
            {
                var process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(ExternalCommands[input])
                {
                    UseShellExecute = false
                };

                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();

                return 0;
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"{input} NOT FOUND");
            return 1;
        }
        catch
        {
            return 1;
        }
```

Comment: Will you need functions or subroutines?  Having a return parameter adds to the complexity.  Also, will you be passing parameters into these routines, and will these routines share the return and/or parameter type?  What problem are you trying to solve that a switch statement couldn't address?

Comment: I will be just using functions (voids)

Comment: `void` in C# implies a method with no return type, whereas `function` means something is expected to be returned.  If you have your heart set on this, take a look at `Action` and `Func` delegates for your dictionary value type to see what would fit your use case best.

Comment: Consider staring at Dictionary<string,Action>. This which will reveal the basic premise of calling with “Action a = dict[word]; a();”. Then expand to accept the most generalized required, eg Dictionary<string,Func<string[],int>> or whatever is appropriate.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How you would do this depends upon the method signatures and what, if any, parameters you need to pass. In general, though, you'd need to create a dictionary of delegates. `Action` and `Func` are pretty easy to use in this situation.

Something like this would work:

```
private void Test()
{
    var commands = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
    commands.Add("exit", Exit);
    commands.Add("greet", SayHello);

    commands["greet"]();
    commands["exit"]();
}

private void Exit()
{
    this.Close();
}

private void SayHello()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
}
```

You could also use lambda expressions to add delegates to such a dictionary for even more flexibility:

```
commands.Add("exit", () => this.Close());
commands.Add("greet", () => MessageBox.Show("Hello!"));
```

Answer (score 0):

For `voids` you can use [Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netcore-3.1), if the function has parameters you use `Action<T>` where T is it the type, for example: `Action<string>`. If your functions return something you can use [Func](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netcore-3.1), example for a function which takes a `string` as an input and returns `int`: `Func<string, int>`. You can use these as values for the dictionary. 
Here is an example code for a hello world application:

```
    class Program
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, Action> FunctionsInDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Action>()
        {
            { "helloworld", HelloWorld }
        };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            FunctionsInDictionary["helloworld"].Invoke();

            Thread.Sleep(-1);
        }

        static void HelloWorld()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
```